# .htaccess RewriteRule and jQuery Ajax URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I have this rule in .htaccess which removes the .php file extension.

```
#remove extension file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This works fine for files in the root folder for all jQuery $.get or $.post request.

The problem is coming from files inside folders. I am getting a 404 error. 
For example, these work fine:

```
$.post('../user/post.php', data).done(function(result){ <-- .php extension added
   //result
}

$.post('register', data).done(function(result){ <-- no file extension and file in root folder
  //result
}
```

This does not:

```
$.post('../user/post', data).done(function(result){
  //result
}
```

File structure:

```
app
 js (folder)
  -app.js
 user (folder)
  -post.php
 dashboard.php
 index.php 
 register.php
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file located, what else do you have in there? What main document URL are you on, when you refer back up using `../`?

Comment: @CBroe that is all I have in the .htaccess file for now. The document URL is https://mydomain/dashboard. /dashboard is a PHP file inside the root folder (dashboard.php).

Comment: With `https://mydomain/dashboard`, you’d be in the root folder. Trying to go one level up using `../` would not make much sense then to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe I have added the file structure. Since app.js in inside the js folder and post.php is inside the user folder, shouldn't I use "../" to go one level up, then the file?

Comment: The location of your app.js has nothing to do with this - the location of your main document that you are executing this _in_, is what these relative URLs will get resolved again.

Comment: I think the problem is with the rules in the .htaccess file. If I add the .php extension to the URL, it works fine. No idea what to do.